# ITextsharp PDF Merge full text layer issue

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

I'm having an issue when merging PDF's using ITextsharp, or more specifically with the Text layer of the PDF after the merge.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
string path = @"C:\temp\Combined.pdf";
List<string> list = new List<String>();
list.Add(@"C:\temp\1.pdf");
list.Add(@"C:\temp\2.pdf");
list.Add(@"C:\temp\3.pdf");
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    // ITextSharp
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;    
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfSmartCopy pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, fileStream);
    pdfCopy.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
    pdfCopy.SetTagged();
    document.Open();
    foreach (string pdfDoc in list)
    {
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfDoc);
        pdfCopy.AddDocument(pdfReader);  
    }
    pdfCopy.Close();
    document.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();

}
```

So the two PDF documents before merging have a fully working usual text layer meaning I can copy and paste the text into notepad and see everything fine.

After merging the documents there appears to be extra spaces added to the text layer:
Text layer example:-

Before Merge: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

After Merge: T h e q u i c k bro w n f o x jump s o v e r t h e lazy d o g

There isn't a constant space between each letter, it's more random than that. Any pointers as to what could be wrong, or something I'm not doing in the PDF merge to retain the text layer?

Samples:

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you share the sample files in question?

Comment: Hi, Sorry they aren't the sort of documents I can share easily, I'll try and create some universal ones, but would have to test them all first.

Comment: *I'll try and create some universal ones, but would have to test them all first.* - if the issue can be reproduced using other PDFs, supplying them is ok, too. By the way, you talk anout *copy and paste the text into notepad* but don't say **from** which application. Have you tested with one PDF viewer only? Or have you tested with multiple ones?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Reader to copy the text and paste into notepad. In the single page documents the text layer is perfect but after the merge is when the issues occur. Currently looking at SetTagged as I have noticed in the PDF properties that this is set to true on the original and false on the merged document.

Comment: Seems the SetTagged() helps, although it's not consistent with it's results, sometimes working perfectly, sometimes the second page is back to how it was. :(

Comment: Have amended the code to reflect the SetTagged function which helps to a degree, but when merging the two files, page 1 is fine, page 2 is not.

Comment: I just applied your code to your two sample documents (so without the `list.Add(@"C:\temp\3.pdf");` line of code), opened the resulting PDF in Adobe Reader and compared the text extracted from it with the text extracted from the respective source document. I could find no differences. I used iTextSharp 5.5.7 and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2015.009.20077.

Comment: Therefore, please also share your merge result and explain exactly by copying what part of the text you get extra spaces where.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I've uploaded my Combined.Pdf file. I found that occasionally the 2 pages would work fine, and then trying again they did not. Please see the combined PDF, page 2 is repeated to make page 3. Yet the copy and paste text layer for page 2 has spaces whereas page 3 does not.
I'm using iTextShare 5.5.7 and Adobe Acrobat Reader XI 11.0.13
I have just passed this over to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015.009.20071 as it seems fine!  Strange!

Comment: I just checked your combined document. I could find no differences in the copy&paste results for page 2 and page 3, neither in Reader DC nor in Acrobat 9.5.5 (the versions I have installed locally). I continued and checked the content streams. They are identical. I had a quick glance at the structure elements (the extra data backing *tagged PDFs*) and what I found should not have an impact on text extraction. Thus, unless some weird details of the structure elements play a role here (I don't know them that well), the document should be ok and the issue in the viewer.

Comment: Okay so it's a viewer issue.
Thank you very much for checking in detail. Much Appreciated.